# Construct a QByteArray from a HEX value entered as a QString

Tags: qt

If `QString str = "0xFFFF"`, how to turn this text representation of an hex into a QByteArray? In the end, I would like to have the same of what I get from the following:

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.resize(2);
ba[0] = 0xFF;
ba[1] = 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In either case the final `QByteArray` would be a sequence of hex values, i.e. `FFFF`. Conversion should be applied on *that* string. Given that, if your input string is provided prepended with the `0x`, you should get rid of it via `mid()`.

Here is a code snippet which compares the results of the two approaches: manually filling the `QByteArray` with hex values or converting hex values from a `QString`:

```
QByteArray array1;
array1.resize(2);
array1[0] = 0xFF;
array1[1] = 0xFF;

QString str = "0xFFFF";   
QString value =  str.mid(2);    // "FFFF"   <- just the hex values!
QByteArray array2 = QByteArray::fromHex(value.toLatin1());  

qDebug() << array1;             // not printable chars 
qDebug() << array2;

qDebug() << array1.toHex();     // to have a printable form use "toHex()"!
qDebug() << array2.toHex();
```